# swagger-ui-express and yamljs: GCP deployment failed OperationError: code=3, message=Function failed on loading user code

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, swagger, swagger-ui

I integrated swagger UI using swagger-ui-express and yamljs packages, in local it works perfectly fine, but while deploying to gcp it throws error

**Step #2: Already have image (with digest): gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud
Step #2: Created .gcloudignore file. See `gcloud topic gcloudignore` for details.
Step #2: Deploying function (may take a while - up to 2 minutes)...
Step #2: WARNING: Setting IAM policy failed, try `gcloud alpha functions add-iam-policy-binding
Step #2: .
Step #2: For Cloud Build Logs, visit: url
Step #2: ....................................failed.
Step #2: ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) OperationError: code=3, message=Function failed on loading user code. This is likely due to a bug in the user code. Error message: Error: please examine your function logs to see the error cause: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/monitoring/logging#viewing_logs. Additional troubleshooting documentation can be found at https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting#logging. Please visit https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting for in-depth troubleshooting documentation.
Finished Step #2
ERROR
ERROR: build step 2 "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 1**

package.json file

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "tslint --project tsconfig.json",
    "build": "tsc",
    "serve": "npm run build && firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "npm run build && firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions:connect_grab_auth_apis_dev",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log",
    "server": "cd src && nodemon server.ts",
    "dev": "tsc && node lib/server.js"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "^12.0.0"
  },
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/secret-manager": "^3.2.0",
    "@types/jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.0",
    "axios": "^0.21.0",
    "bcrypt": "^5.0.0",
    "bluebird": "^3.7.2",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "eslint": "^7.13.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-openapi-validator": "^4.13.7",
    "firebase-admin": "^9.2.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.6.1",
    "http-status-codes": "^2.1.4",
    "joi": "^17.3.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.0.0",
    "mysql": "github:mysqljs/mysql",
    "promise-mysql": "^4.1.3",
    "swagger-ui-express": "^4.3.0",
    "tslint": "^6.1.3",
    "uuid": "^8.3.1",
    "winston": "^3.3.3",
    "yamljs": "^0.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/bcrypt": "^3.0.0",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.8",
    "@types/jwt-decode": "^2.2.1",
    "@types/mysql": "^2.15.15",
    "@types/uuid": "^8.3.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^3.9.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^3.8.0",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.2.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.6",
    "ts-node": "^9.0.0",
    "typescript": "^3.9.7"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

server.ts

```
import express from 'express';
const swaggerUI = require('swagger-ui-express');
const yaml = require('yamljs');
const path = require("path");
import { errorMiddleware } from './middleware/error.middleware';
import * as oauth from './routes/oauth.route';

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());

// Serve the OpenAPI spec
const swaggerJsDocs = yaml.load(path.resolve(__dirname, "./api.yaml"))
app.use('/docs', swaggerUI.serve, swaggerUI.setup(swaggerJsDocs));

app.use('/oauth', oauth.router);
app.use(errorMiddleware);

export default app;
```

index.ts

```
import { HttpsFunction, https } from 'firebase-functions';
import express from 'express';
import app from './app';

const main = express();
main.use('/test', app);

export const a: HttpsFunction = https.onRequest(main);
export const b: HttpsFunction = https.onRequest(main);
export const c: HttpsFunction = https.onRequest(main);
```